# can't connect to gitlab repository from VPS

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, gitlab, putty

I'm using gitlab repository for version control.
there is no problem when i run following commands on localhost.

```
$ git pull origin master

$ git remote show origin

$ git clone ...
```

but when i run same commands on my `vps` i get this error after about 20 seconds:

> ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out fatal:
>   The remote end hung up unexpectedly

please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VPS provider:

> port 22 on your server was blocked and we unblocked that.

And now working :)